# Pass JsonData from view and receive JSON return value in view

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to send data by user input to controller using ajax and want to execute query by user input. Later I want to return the query result to same view by a JsonResult. I have successfully sent data to controller but can't find the way to return the query and shows it in same view.

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit";
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr No</th>
        <th>Party Name </th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Deposit</th>
        <th>Action</th>

    </tr>

    @{


        int count = 1;
    }

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@count</td>
            <td>@Model.Rows[i][1]</td>
            <td>@Model.Rows[i][2]</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Deposit", null, new { placeholder = "Input" })</td>

            <td>   <input type="submit" value="Deposit" id="btnClick" /></td>

        </tr>

        count++;
    }

</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ProductPack = JSON.stringify({
                'Deposit': $("#Deposit").val(),

                });
            $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                var f = {};
                f.url = '@Url.Action("InsertDeposit", "Admin")';
                f.type = "POST";
                f.dataType = "json";
                f.data = JSON.stringify({
                    'Deposit': $("#txtValue").val()

                });
                f.contentType = "application/json";
                f.success = function (response) {
                    location.reload();
                    if (response == true) {
                        window.location.href='Negative';
                    }
                    alert("success");
                };
                f.error = function (response) {
                    alert("failed");
                };
                $.ajax(f);
            });
        });

    </script>
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deposit";
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr No</th>
        <th>Party Name </th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Deposit</th>
        <th>Action</th>

    </tr>

    @{


        int count = 1;
    }

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@count</td>
            <td>@Model.Rows[i][1]</td>
            <td>@Model.Rows[i][2]</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Deposit", null, new { placeholder = "Input" })</td>

            <td>   <input type="submit" value="Deposit" id="btnClick" /></td>

        </tr>

        count++;
    }

</table>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ProductPack = JSON.stringify({
                'Deposit': $("#Deposit").val(),

                });
            $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                var f = {};
                f.url = '@Url.Action("InsertDeposit", "Admin")';
                f.type = "POST";
                f.dataType = "json";
                f.data = JSON.stringify({
                    'Deposit': $("#txtValue").val()

                });
                f.contentType = "application/json";
                f.success = function (response) {
                    location.reload();
                    if (response == true) {
                        window.location.href='Negative';
                    }
                    alert("success");
                };
                f.error = function (response) {
                    alert("failed");
                };
                $.ajax(f);
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Controller code:

```
public JsonResult InsertDeposit(string Deposit, string PartyId, string EmployeId)
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    int Pid = Convert.ToInt32(PartyId);

    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string query = $"Select  * from Party  where PartyId = @PartyId";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartyId", Pid);

        sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    }

    return Json(new
    {
        resut = "OK got it"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the datatable to json by passing it to ASP.NET's Json method:

```
return Json(dtbl);
```

But understand that if you call the controller with ajax and get the response in json format, you will have to render that data on the page with client-side script (javascript). You will not be able to use the view template which you have pasted in the question because it is only used on the server side by asp.net.

I don't know why you want to use ajax, but perhaps a better way to do this would be to have a classic html form and submit it on the button click. Then you change your controller to return type IActionResult and the last line to `return View(dtbl);`. This way you can utilize the view template you have.

Comment: JsonResult type function doesn't allow return View();

Comment: So, how can i redirect a view after JsoResult